# What is the best way to find solved problems similar to the one at hand?

Tags: dynamics, fluid

This is a general question, so sorry if it breaks the rules. However, I think it is very important as more often than not someone else has already solved a similar problem that can be applied to solve the problem at hand or at least give clues on how to proceed.

For example, I was trying to figure out a way to distribute fluid flow evenly across several openings in a channel. Luckily a short google search revealed an article ”Flow distribution in manifolds” which was precisely what I was looking for.

What do you think is the most efficient method of finding similar problems that have already been solved?

Comment: Reading is good...